# - RESOLVED - Javascript 'onMouseMove' / CSS :hover conflict

Tags: javascript, css, hover, conflict

I have an issue with my web project.
I used a js script to create a "neon queue" effect that follows my mouse pointer when moving the mouse on the screen and that works fine. 
I used a css property on my menu items to make them glow when hovered.

The thing is, it is working BUT the css effect only applies once the neon circles have completely disappeared.How can I avoid this waiting ?

First I thought it was because of the circles passing over the div but then I set z-indexes and it still is causing problems.

Here is the html code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menu">

    <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"/> 
        <ul>
            <li class="item">WEB</li>
            <li class="item">VPS</li>
            <li class="item">SERVEUR DEDIE</li>
            <li class="item">HOUSING</li>
        </ul>
      </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the script, I followed a youtube tutorial and adapted it a bit :

```
 document.onmousemove = animateCircles;


function animateCircles(event){
    var circle = document.createElement("div");
    circle.setAttribute("class","circle");
    document.body.appendChild(circle);
    circle.style.left = event.clientX+'px';
    circle.style.top= event.clientY+'px';    
    deletecircle(circle);

}

function deletecircle(fadeTarget) {    
var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
    if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
    }
    if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.1;


    } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        fadeTarget.parentNode.removeChild(fadeTarget);
    }
}, 50);
}
```

And finally the css properties :

```
    html{
    height: 100%;
}
body { 

    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#070b13, #1c2641);
    background-position: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fdfdfd;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;

}

/* MENU ##################################################################################*/
#menu {
    width: 300px;
    font-size: 25px;    
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    z-index:10;
}

#menu li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 40px;   
    opacity: 0.7;     
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in !important; 
    z-index: 10;
}

/*
#menu li:hover{    
    color: #00f6ff !important; 
    opacity: 1 !important;
    text-shadow:0 0 20px #31ccff !important; 
    z-index: 10 !important;
}*/

#menu .logo {
    height: 16px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    position: absolute;
}

/* MOUSE ANIMATION ##############################################################################*/
.circle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #00f6ff;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31ccff;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The divs that you are generating for the circles get in front of the menu items. The z-index properties you have set aren't working because the circle divs aren't positioned relatively to the menu items.

Setting the circle class to have a z-index of -1 appears to resolve the issue, as this effectively forces the absolutely positioned circle divs to appear behind other content on the page.

Your circle class becomes the following:

```
.circle {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #00f6ff;
    border-radius:50%;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #31ccff;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8vo1jL5/

Comment: Thank you very much it works ! I thought putting 0 to the cirlces and 10 to the menu divs was enough, and i feared that -1 would be sending the circles behind the background lol but yeah, you solved my issue and resolved the issue :)